# MongoDB express app showing empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new at MongoDB / Node.js / express. I'm setting up an app following this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB9Fq9I5ocs

I've created a db called "chatbot" and 2 collections within "chatbot": "countries" and "populations".

However, when I try to run the app to display the countries that I created in the shell, I get nothing but an empty array.

Here is the collection "countries":

```
> db.countries.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58a0c3234d9ba38dcbe1769d"), "name" : "Afghanistan" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58a0c3844d9ba38dcbe1769e"), "name" : "Andorra" }
```

Here are my app files:
package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "chatbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "chatbot app",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "mongoose": "*"
  },
  "author": "Chris",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

Country = require('./models/country.js');

// Connect to Mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ChatbotService')
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hola');
});

app.get('/api/countries', function(req, res){
    Country.getCountries(function(err, countries){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(countries);
    });
});

app.listen(8601);
console.log('Running on port 8601...');
```

country.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Country Schema
var countrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

var Country = module.exports = mongoose.model('Country', countrySchema);

// Get Countries
module.exports.getCountries = function(callback, limit){
    Country.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

This is what I'm getting when I reload:
[image: result after reload]
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chatbot is your db name but here
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ChatbotService') you are using chatbotservice. I think you are connecting with different db here.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the document name in the schema like:

```
var countrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}, { **document name** });
```